# How can I use ExifTool to rename .HEICS files by the file modify date?

Tags: exiftool, macos

The following ExifTool command renames many file types in the current directory by file modify date (e.g., `.HEIC`, `.JPG`, `.jpeg`):

`exiftool -d "%Y/%m/%y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S 0%%c.%%e" "-filename<filemodifydate" .`

The `.HEIC`, `.JPG`, `.jpeg` files get renamed into a format like the following, based on the file modify date:

`./2010/10/10-10-01 06-55-23 0.JPG`

The command does not rename `.HEICS` files. How can I use ExifTool to make `.HEICS` files get renamed like the other file types do?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have been trying to use ExifTool with `.HEICS` files. They are sort of like .GIF files, I imported them from my phone. It turns out that as of today ExifTool doesn't support `.HEICS` files.

Comment: Have you tried running exiftool directly on the HEICS file?  It could be that exiftool can process it but doesn't recognize the extension.  If that doesn't work, you could see if the author of exiftool could add support by posting in the [ExifTool Feature Request forum](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?board=6.0).

Comment: If you have a HEICS sample file that can be shared, then exiftool will probably be able to  add support.  Phil, the author of exiftool, doesn't have any sample HEICS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.HEICS` file extension is not listed as a [Exiftool supported file type](https://exiftool.org/#supported).

Running `exiftool -listf` will show you all of the file extensions supported by your installation of Exiftool. I just updated mine and ran it, and `.HEICS` did not appear in the supported file extentions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! This answers my question. I have been using ExifTool 12.69 which was released Oct. 26, 2023.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically [Exiftool FAQ #16](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q16)

If you're just renaming by the file system time stamp, then exiftool doesn't need to support the file type.  It can read the `FileModifyDate` without parsing the file.

But since HEICS isn't technically writable, it will be skipped.

You can use the [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) to tell exiftool to process the HEICS files by adding this to your command
`-ext+ HEICS`

Comment: I'm checking with the author of exiftool to see if HEICS files are actually supported and the extension fell through the cracks.  Also, it would be helpful if a sample HEICS file can be provided, as my searches for one only pull up the plural of HEIC.

Comment: I searched on how to create a HEICS file. Damn Google for removing "+[term]" and "-[term]" hard searching because of their aborted/failed Google+ fiasco. Searching for ".HEICS" (required) and trying to eliminate extraneous "HEIC" is virtually impossible. Anyhow, all my Apple "Live Photos" are .HEIC files, and I can't figure out how to create a .HEICS sequence. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I checked with Phil, the author of exiftool, and he doesn't have any HEICS sample files in order to check what, if any, changes need to be done to add exiftool support.